# Speed up proxy connection download speed

Tags: proxy, download

In my country http://youtube.com is banned and I cannot download from it so I used proxy(with Freegate),but now the download speed comes down(instead of 60KB/sec it's now about 20KB/s).

why this occurs and Is there any way to speed it up?

Comment: Free proxies are usually well frequented or outright overloaded.

Answer (score -1):

It occurs because you have to receive more data, if not, the same amount of data you would as you were to go to the website regularly. I would say 60 KB/s is really bad, even if you were only going to use the internet for e-mail. I would recommend about 3 MB/s if you can get it.

Comment: While true, it is not the case that you receive three times as much data while proxying youtube. A little extra, sure, but not three times as much.

Comment: Well, I'm not saying 3 times as much. I'm just recommending to get a faster plan to be able to use the internet in better ways than he can now.

Comment: I'm downvoting this, because the overhead amounts to a few tens of bytes and as such is negligible.